# Failed to initialize the device agent

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to run via android studio a app on my mobile that is connected via USB but I cannot see my mobile display in android studio I get the error Failed to initialize the device agent.

[image]

Why do I get t his error?

Comment: Check the logcat (can be found at the bottom of your screenshot) for the error message mentioned in the preview tab and paste it here, it might show the reason why

Answer (score -3):

You should close the device mirroring. You can uncheck "Enable mirroring of physical Android devices" from File>>Settings>>Tools>>Device Mirroring on Andoid Studio 2022.3.1 Patch 2 (Windows PC). Then you will not get any error like that.